# Join two consumers into a single consumer that returns multiple values?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have been experimenting with the new pipes-http package and I had a thought.  I have two parsers for a web page, one that returns line items and another a number from elsewhere in the page.  When I grab the page, it'd be nice to string these parsers together and get their results at the same time from the same bytestring producer, rather than fetching the page twice or fetching all the html into memory and parsing it twice.

In other words, say you have two Consumers:

```
c1 :: Consumer a m r1
c2 :: Consumer a m r2
```

Is it possible to make a function like this:

```
combineConsumers :: Consumer a m r1 -> Consumer a m r2 -> Consumer a m (r1, r2)
combineConsumers = undefined
```

I have tried a few things, but I can't figure it out.  I understand if it isn't possible, but it would be convenient.

Edit:

I'm sorry it turns out I was making an assumption about pipes-attoparsec, due to my experience with conduit-attoparsec that caused me to ask the wrong question.  Pipes-attoparsec turns an attoparsec into a pipes Parser when I just assumed that it would return a pipes Consumer.  That means that I can't actually turn two attoparsec parsers into consumers that take text and return a result, then use them with the plain old pipes ecosystem.  I'm sorry but I just don't understand pipes-parse.

Even though it doesn't help me, Arthur's answer is pretty much what I envisioned when I asked the question, and I'll probably end up using his solution in the future.  In the meantime I'm just going to use conduit.

Comment: Can you link to one or both of the consumers as example? Most of pipes code I am familiar with does not use consumer's base value is not used this way.  If you are not using the base value on the other hand it is trivial zip two consumers together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something is wrong with the way you are going about this, for the reasons Davorak mentions in his remark.  But if you really need such a function, you can define it.

```
import Pipes.Internal
import Pipes.Core

zipConsumers :: Monad m => Consumer a m r -> Consumer a m s -> Consumer a m (r,s)
zipConsumers p q = go (p,q) where
  go (p,q) = case (p,q) of 
     (Pure r     , Pure s)      -> Pure (r,s)
     (M mpr      , ps)          -> M (do pr <- mpr
                                         return (go (pr, ps)))
     (pr         , M mps)       -> M (do ps <- mps
                                         return (go (pr, ps)))
     (Request _ f, Request _ g) -> Request () (\a -> go (f a, g a))
     (Request _ f, Pure s)      -> Request () (\a -> do r <- f a
                                                        return (r, s))
     (Pure r     , Request _ g) -> Request () (\a -> do s <- g a
                                                        return (r,s))
     (Respond x _, _          ) -> closed x
     (_          , Respond y _) -> closed y
```

If you are 'zipping' consumers without using their return value, only their 'effects' you can just use `tee consumer1 >-> consumer2`

Answer (score 3):

It the results are "monoidal", you can use the `tee` function from the Pipes prelude, in combination with a `WriterT`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Writer.Class
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Data.Text as T

textSource :: Producer T.Text IO ()
textSource = yield "foo" >> yield "bar" >> yield "foo" >> yield "nah"

counter :: Monoid w => T.Text 
                    -> (T.Text -> w) 
                    -> Consumer T.Text (WriterT w IO) ()
counter word inject = P.filter (==word) >-> P.mapM (tell . inject) >-> P.drain

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <-runWriterT $ runEffect $ 
        hoist lift textSource >-> 
        P.tee (counter "foo" inject1) >-> (counter "bar" inject2)
    putStrLn . show $ result
    where
    inject1 _ = (,) (Sum 1) mempty
    inject2 _ = (,) mempty (Sum 1)
```

**Update:** As mentioned in a comment, the real problem I see is that in `pipes` parsers aren't `Consumers`. And how can you run two parsers concurrently if they have different behaviours regarding leftovers? What happens if one of the parsers wants to "un-draw" some text and the other parser doesn't?

One possible solution is to run the parsers in a truly concurrent manner, in different threads. The primitives in the `pipes-concurrency` package let you "duplicate" a `Producer` by writing the same data to two different mailboxes. And then each parser can do whatever it wants with its own copy of the producer. Here's an example which also uses the `pipes-parse`, `pipes-attoparsec` and `async` packages:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Attoparsec.Text hiding (takeWhile)
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.Attoparsec as P
import qualified Pipes.Concurrent as P
import qualified Control.Concurrent.Async as A

parseChars :: Char -> Parser [Char] 
parseChars c = fmap mconcat $ 
    many (notChar c) *> many1 (some (char c) <* many (notChar c))

textSource :: Producer T.Text IO ()
textSource = yield "foo" >> yield "bar" >> yield "foo" >> yield "nah"

parseConc :: Producer T.Text IO () 
          -> Parser a 
          -> Parser b 
          -> IO (Either P.ParsingError a,Either P.ParsingError b)
parseConc producer parser1 parser2 = do
    (outbox1,inbox1,seal1) <- P.spawn' P.Unbounded
    (outbox2,inbox2,seal2) <- P.spawn' P.Unbounded
    feeding <- A.async $ runEffect $ producer >-> P.tee (P.toOutput outbox1) 
                                              >->        P.toOutput outbox2
    sealing <- A.async $ A.wait feeding >> P.atomically seal1 >> P.atomically seal2
    r <- A.runConcurrently $ 
        (,) <$> (A.Concurrently $ parseInbox parser1 inbox1)
            <*> (A.Concurrently $ parseInbox parser2 inbox2)
    A.wait sealing
    return r 
    where
    parseInbox parser inbox = evalStateT (P.parse parser) (P.fromInput inbox)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (Right a, Right b) <- parseConc textSource (parseChars 'o')  (parseChars 'a')
    putStrLn . show $ (a,b)
```

The result is:

```
("oooo","aa")
```

I'm not sure how much overhead this approach introduces.

Comment: Unfortunately my results are not monoidal.  I could use state, I guess.  I suppose I could also use iorefs.

Comment: @mindreader You can always use `First` and `Last` from `Data.Monoid` to "make a monoid" out of any type. The real problem I see is that, in `pipes`, `Parsers` are not `Consumers`. Also, leftover processing when running two parsers in paralell is likely to be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic solution is to rewrite your `Consumer`s as a `Fold` or `FoldM` from the `foldl` library and then combine them using `Applicative` style.  You can then convert this combined fold to one that works on pipes.

Let's assume that you either have two `Fold`s:

```
fold1 :: Fold a r1
fold2 :: Fold a r2
```

... or two `FoldM`s:

```
foldM1 :: Monad m => FoldM a m r1
foldM2 :: Monad m => FoldM a m r2
```

Then you combine these into a single `Fold`/`FoldM` using `Applicative` style:

```
import Control.Applicative

foldBoth :: Fold a (r1, r2)
foldBoth = (,) <$> fold1 <*> fold2

foldBothM :: Monad m => FoldM a m (r1, r2)
foldBothM = (,) <$> foldM1 <*> foldM2

-- or: foldBoth  = liftA2 (,) fold1  fold2
--     foldMBoth = liftA2 (,) foldM1 foldM2
```

You can turn either fold into a `Pipes.Prelude`-style fold or a `Parser`.  Here are the necessary conversion functions:

```
import Control.Foldl (purely, impurely)
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Parse   as Parse

purely Pipes.fold
    :: Monad m => Fold a b -> Producer a m () -> m b

impurely Pipes.foldM
    :: Monad m => FoldM m a b -> Producer a m () -> m b

purely Parse.foldAll
    :: Monad m => Fold a b -> Parser a m r

impurely Parse.foldMAll
    :: Monad m => FoldM a m b -> Parser a m r
```

The reason for the `purely` and `impurely` functions is so that `foldl` and `pipes` can interoperate without either one incurring a dependency on the other.  Also, they allow libraries other than `pipes` (like `conduit`) to reuse `foldl` without a dependency, too (Hint hint, @MichaelSnoyman).

I apologize that this feature is not documented, mainly because it took me a while to figure out how to get `pipes` and `foldl` to interoperate in a dependency-free manner, and that was after I wrote the `pipes` tutorial.  I will update the tutorial to point out this trick.

To learn how to use `foldl`, just read [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.0.2/docs/Control-Foldl.html) in the main module.  It's a very small and easy-to-learn library.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, in the conduit world, the relevant function is [zipSinks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.13.1/docs/Data-Conduit-Util.html#v%3azipSinks). There might be some way to adapt this function to work for pipes, but automatic termination may get in the way.

Comment: Well that is convenient.  Given the existence of attoparsec-conduit, maybe I should consider using conduit instead in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer forms a Monad so

```
combineConsumers = liftM2 (,)
```

will type check. Unfortunately, the semantics might be unlike what you're expecting: the first consumer will run to completion and then the second.