# Why does this not run in constant memory?

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation, bytestring, writefile

I am trying to write a very large amount of data to a file in constant memory.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

{- Creates and writes num grids of dimensions aa x aa -}
writeGrids :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
writeGrids num aa = do
    rng <- newPureMT
    let (grids,shuffleds) = createGrids rng aa
    createDirectoryIfMissing True "data/grids/"
    B.writeFile (gridFileName num aa)
                (encode (take num grids))
    B.writeFile (shuffledFileName num aa)
                (encode (take num shuffleds))
```

However this consumes memory proportional to the size of `num`. I know `createGrids` is a sufficiently lazy function because I have tested it by appending `error "not lazy enough"` (as suggested by the [Haskell wiki here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maintaining_laziness)) to the end of the lists it returns and no errors are raised. `take` is a lazy function that is defined in `Data.List`. `encode` is also a lazy function defined in `Data.Binary`. `B.writeFile` is defined in `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.

Here is the complete code so you can execute it:

```
import Control.Arrow (first)
import Data.Binary
import GHC.Float (double2Float)
import System.Random (next)
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64 (PureMT, newPureMT, randomDouble)
import System.Random.Shuffle (shuffle')
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

main :: IO ()
main = writeGrids 1000 64

{- Creates and writes num grids of dimensions aa x aa -}
writeGrids :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
writeGrids num aa = do
    rng <- newPureMT
    let (grids,shuffleds) = createGrids rng aa
    B.writeFile "grids.bin" (encode (take num grids))
    B.writeFile "shuffleds.bin" (encode (take num shuffleds))

{- a random number generator, dimension of grids to make
   returns a pair of lists, the first is a list of grids of dimensions
   aa x aa, the second is a list of the shuffled grids corresponding to the first list -}
createGrids :: PureMT -> Int -> ([[(Float,Float)]],[[(Float,Float)]])
createGrids rng aa = (grids,shuffleds) where
       rs = randomFloats rng
       grids = map (getGridR aa) (chunksOf (2 * aa * aa) rs) 
       shuffleds = shuffler (aa * aa) rng grids

{- length of each grid, a random number generator, a list of grids
   returns a the list with each grid shuffled -}
shuffler :: Int -> PureMT -> [[(Float,Float)]] -> [[(Float,Float)]]
shuffler n rng (xs:xss) = shuffle' xs n rng : shuffler n (snd (next rng))         xss
shuffler _ _ [] = []

{- divides list into chunks of size n -}
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n = go 
     where go xs = case splitAt n xs of
              (ys,zs) | null ys -> []
                      | otherwise -> ys : go zs

{- dimension of grid, list of random floats [0,1]
   returns a list of (x,y) points of length n^2 such that all
   points are in the range [0,1] and the points are a randomly 
   perturbed regular grid -}
getGridR :: Int -> [Float] -> [(Float,Float)]
getGridR n rs = pts where
   nn = n * n
   (irs,jrs) = splitAt nn rs
   n' = fromIntegral n
   grid = [ (p,q) | p <- [0..n'-1], q <- [0..n'-1] ]
   pts = zipWith (\(p,q) (ir,jr) -> ((p+ir)/n',(q+jr)/n')) grid (zip irs jrs)

{- an infinite list of random floats in range [0,1] -}
randomFloats :: PureMT -> [Float]
randomFloats rng = let (d,rng') = first double2Float (randomDouble rng)
                   in d : randomFloats rng'
```

The required packages are:
                     , bytestring
                     , binary
                     , random
                     , mersenne-random-pure64
                     , random-shuffle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two reasons for the memory usage:

**First**, `Data.Binary.encode` doesn't seem to run in constant space. The following program uses 910 MB memory:

```
import Data.Binary
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

len = 10000000 :: Int 

main = B.writeFile "grids.bin" $ encode [0..len]
```

If we leave a `0` out from `len` we get 97 MB memory usage.

In contrast, the following program uses 1 MB:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

main = B.writeFile "grids.bin" $ B.pack $ show [0..(1000000::Int)]
```

**Second**, in your program `shuffleds` contains references to contents of `grids`, which prevents garbage collection of `grids`. So when we print `grids`, we also evaluate it and then it has to sit in memory until we finish printing `shuffleds`. The following version of your program still consumes lots of memory, but it uses constant space if we comment out one of the two lines with `B.writeFile`.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

writeGrids :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
writeGrids num aa = do
    rng <- newPureMT
    let (grids,shuffleds) = createGrids rng aa
    B.writeFile "grids.bin" (B.pack $ show (take num grids))
    B.writeFile "shuffleds.bin" (B.pack $ show (take num shuffleds))
```

Comment: re the first point: The `Binary` instance for `[a]` forces the spine of the list with `length`

Comment: The format of Binary encoded bytestrings is `Word64 big endian length || data`.  Which explains the strict spine mentioned by jberryman.  One could easily make a serialization of chunks and terminating boolean, making an encoding form like `Word16 big endian chunk size || Chunk || False || Chunk || .. || True`.  This should be able to run in size O(chunk size). To keep the previous format you'd have to re-write the first field, making your IO slightly more complex.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, here is a full solution combining the ideas of everyone here. Memory consumption is constant at ~6MB (compiled with `-O2`).

```
import Control.Arrow (first)
import Control.Monad.State (state, evalState)
import Data.Binary
import GHC.Float (double2Float)
import System.Random (next)
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64 (PureMT, newPureMT, randomDouble)
import System.Random.Shuffle (shuffle')
import qualified Data.ByteString as B (hPut)
import qualified Pipes.Binary as P (encode)
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P (zip, mapM, drain)
import Pipes (runEffect, (>->))
import System.IO (withFile, IOMode(AppendMode))

main :: IO ()
main = writeGrids 1000 64

{- Creates and writes num grids of dimensions aa x aa -}
writeGrids :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
writeGrids num aa = do
    rng <- newPureMT
    let (grids, shuffleds) = createGrids rng aa
        gridFile = "grids.bin"
        shuffledFile = "shuffleds.bin"
        encoder = P.encode . SerList . take num
    writeFile gridFile ""
    writeFile shuffledFile ""
    withFile gridFile AppendMode $ \hGr ->
        withFile shuffledFile AppendMode $ \hSh ->
            runEffect
                $ P.zip (encoder grids) (encoder shuffleds)
                >-> P.mapM (\(ch1, ch2) -> B.hPut hGr ch1 >> B.hPut hSh ch2)
                >-> P.drain -- discards the stream of () results.

{- a random number generator, dimension of grids to make
   returns a pair of lists, the first is a list of grids of dimensions
   aa x aa, the second is a list of the shuffled grids corresponding to the first list -}
createGrids :: PureMT -> Int -> ( [[(Float,Float)]], [[(Float,Float)]] )
createGrids rng aa = unzip gridsAndShuffleds where
       rs = randomFloats rng
       grids =  map (getGridR aa) (chunksOf (2 * aa * aa) rs)
       gridsAndShuffleds = shuffler (aa * aa) rng grids

{- length of each grid, a random number generator, a list of grids
   returns a the list with each grid shuffled -}
shuffler :: Int -> PureMT -> [[(Float,Float)]] -> [( [(Float,Float)], [(Float,Float)] )]
shuffler n rng xss = evalState (traverse oneShuffle xss) rng
    where
    oneShuffle xs = state $ \r -> ((xs, shuffle' xs n r), snd (next r))

newtype SerList a = SerList { runSerList :: [a] }
    deriving (Show)

instance Binary a => Binary (SerList a) where
    put (SerList (x:xs)) = put False >> put x >> put (SerList xs)
    put _                = put True
    get = do
        stop <- get :: Get Bool
        if stop
            then return (SerList [])
            else do
                x          <- get
                SerList xs <- get
                return (SerList (x : xs))

{- divides list into chunks of size n -}
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n = go 
     where go xs = case splitAt n xs of
              (ys,zs) | null ys -> []
                      | otherwise -> ys : go zs

{- dimension of grid, list of random floats [0,1]
   returns a list of (x,y) points of length n^2 such that all
   points are in the range [0,1] and the points are a randomly 
   perturbed regular grid -}
getGridR :: Int -> [Float] -> [(Float,Float)]
getGridR n rs = pts where
   nn = n * n
   (irs,jrs) = splitAt nn rs
   n' = fromIntegral n
   grid = [ (p,q) | p <- [0..n'-1], q <- [0..n'-1] ]
   pts = zipWith (\(p,q) (ir,jr) -> ((p+ir)/n',(q+jr)/n')) grid (zip irs jrs)

{- an infinite list of random floats in range [0,1] -}
randomFloats :: PureMT -> [Float]
randomFloats rng = let (d,rng') = first double2Float (randomDouble rng)
                   in d : randomFloats rng'
```

Comments on the changes:

- `shuffler` is now a traversal with the `State` functor. It produces, in a single pass through the input list, a list of pairs, in which each grid is paired with its shuffled version. `createGrids` then (lazily) unzips this list.
- The files are written to using [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-binary-0.4.0.4) machinery, in a way loosely inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724930/2751851) (I originally wrote this using `P.foldM`). Note that the `hPut` I used is the strict bytestring one, for it acts on strict chunks supplied by the  producer made with `P.zip` (which, in spirit, is a pair of lazy bytestrings that supplies chunks in pairs).
- `SerList` is there to hold the custom `Binary` instance Thomas M. DuBuisson alludes to. Note that I haven't thought too much about laziness and strictness in the `get` method of the instance. If that causes you trouble, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695373/lazy-decoding-of-a-list-with-data-binary) looks useful.